# Python Module Explanation

Tags: module, beautifulsoup, importerror

Can somebody explain to what I might be doing wrong with modules. I'm trying to use beautifulsoup. I've gone back and forth, installing, deleting beautifulsoup / bs4 I have done this quite a few times.

Whenever I load this file that uses `from bs4 import BeautifulSoup` I get an error saying that there is no module named BeautifulSoup.

Then miraculously yesterday after saving this file under the following path:
Python34/Lib/bs4/bs4/tests

directory, it finally worked. I'm a little confused. If I change the BeautifulSoup to all lowercase beautifulsoup, it tells me

> ImportError: cannot import name BeautifulSoup

I'm confused as to if when I need to use other modules, must they all be under the same directory? Is my logic incorrect? It seems like if there is one small change to anything, my code crumbles or it gives me errors. I've had other errors like, you're trying to compile with Python 2 code or a previous version of BeautifulSoup 3 and not 4. So I've grown quite confused/frustrated. I'm trying to build off of this code below, then slowly expand to more complex things for my project. But first I need to understand the basics.

My code is the following:

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = urlopen("http://www.pythonscraping.com/pages/page1.html")
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(html.read())
print(bsObj.h1)
```

I just don't want to see these import errors anymore.

Comment: Does your response give/define the BeautifulSoup module the same path definition as sys?

Comment: So for my case. I should be importing BeautifulSoup if I'm not under its directory. I should do                             `import BeautifulSoup    sys.path.append('/BeautifulSoup/folder')` that's saying that I want to have one area where I want to keep all my code, then define the path for each module the script should use.

Answer (score 0):

if you are importing packages from another directory you need to add path before importing.

```
import sys
sys.path.append('pathToBeatifulSoup')
```

eg.
if your package is in `/package/folder1/`

```
import sys
sys.path.append('/package/folder1/')
```